# When implementing a system call, how do you expose the system call number to userland?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm fiddling with system calls. I've added two new ones and verified they work using calls to `syscall`.

I would like the syscall numbers to be in a header so that userspace does not have to know the syscall number explicitly.

In `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` I have:

```
317     64      krun_read_msrs                  sys_krun_read_msrs
318     64      krun_reset_msrs                 sys_krun_reset_msrs
```

And some grepping suggests that kbuild has auto-generated the macros for the new syscalls:

```
$ ag __NR_krun *
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
321:#define __NR_krun_read_msrs 317
322:#define __NR_krun_reset_msrs 318
```

The filename suggests that I don't need to add the entries manually, but this is contrary to what the Linux Kernel docs have to say:

```
Some architectures (e.g. x86) have their own architecture-specific syscall tables, but several other architectures share a generic syscall table. Add your new system call to the generic list by adding an entry to the list in include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h:

#define __NR_xyzzy 292
__SYSCALL(__NR_xyzzy, sys_xyzzy)
```

Well, my syscalls are x86_64 specific, since they read and write MSRs found only in Intel chips. So after this, I went digging to see if I could find the arch-specific header for my amd64 system.

You would expect it to be under `arch/x86_64` but there are no includes at all in there. So I assume x86_64 inherits from `x86`. That being the case, the arch-specific header should be:

```
arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h
```

If you open that up, it's just a little wrapper to dispatch based on arch:

```
# ifdef __i386__                                                                
#  include <asm/unistd_32.h>                                                    
# elif defined(__ILP32__)                                                       
#  include <asm/unistd_x32.h>                                                   
# else                                                                          
#  include <asm/unistd_64.h>                                                    
# endif
```

So that's presumably designed to pick up `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h`, but this does not yet include my new syscall numbers.

I'd expect the `headers_install` target to install the new headers (perhaps), but alas it does not.

I'm confused. Should I add my new syscalls to a file manually or not? If so which file? If not, how do I expose the auto-generated `__NR_*` macros to userspace in a standard location?

Thanks

Comment: You do not necessarily need to, if you implement wrapper functions in a library to call the syscalls. This is, after all, most of what the C libraries do on POSIXy systems. You could have the library header files expose the syscall numbers (appropriate to the current architecture). To include new syscalls to all Linux users, you'd need to push the patch upstream to both the Linux kernel (via LKML), and either the GNU C library, or to specific distributions, so that they add the changes to their system headers.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really feasible, as the syscalls are not suitable for general use.

Comment: What (is not feasible), wrapping the syscalls into functions? (If you mean pushing it upstream, that I do agree.) You really should consider wrapping the syscalls into functions, though; even if just as static inline functions in a header file, choosing the proper syscall number based on the arch and word size (using preprocessor macros). It is much easier to provide the *extra* header file along with the modified kernel (or kernel modifications), than to include the extra items in the standard header files.

Comment: Having wrapper functions would be nice, yes, but the first step really is to try and export `__NR_*` and friends. Would the wrapper functions you propose not depend on those anyway? I just need some way of knowing the syscall number, which may differ per arch or kernel version.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. The problem is, most Linux distributions do not use the userspace headers provided by the kernel; instead, they use header files provided by the C library, and any other development libraries installed. For example, Debian (and Debian derivatives like Ubuntu, Mint, and so on) keeps the kernel headers at at `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/` (for the current one); the syscall numbers for the currently running kernel are in `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`. The wrapper function can use `uname()` C library function to obtain the current [...]

Comment: [...] kernel version, and choose the syscall number based on that. I personally would provide the header file along with the kernel package, with your kernel build extended with both your patch, as well as a patch that generates the header file for that specific kernel. If the syscall number varies from kernel to kernel, then the `uname()` approach is necessary (at the first call); a simple array of kernel versions (and word size on x86-64) with the syscall number should suffice. Ease of maintenance is the key in these cases.

Comment: ok, so I'll try to have the kernel build install a header of my crafting.

Comment: @EddBarrett, syscalls are **by definition**, for general use.  If you are not writing them for that purpose, probably your problem is not well defined. Your interface with the kernel will need to be patched as the kernel evolves, and your premises of writing system calls have to fill this requirement.  If your system calls are not to be of general use, simply don't write them.

Comment: The system calls are for a piece of scientific research. Such is the nature of research I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have a partial answer. Partial because it is Debian specific.

If you use the `make deb-pkg` target in the kernel sources, then `.deb` packages are created in the parent directory. If you then install these, then your headers get installed into the system.

After doing this for my kernel described above:

```
$ grep krun /usr/include
/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h:#define __NR_krun_read_msrs 317
/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h:#define __NR_krun_reset_msrs 318
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual system call numbers assigned by the kernel build process **are part of the kernel build process**... so you don't get the actual final numbers, but only on an already built kernel.   Build your kernel and you'll see the actual assignments in a built header file.  I'm afraid you have tried to search for them in a clean kernel source, and that's the reason you don't find the proper include file.

On other side, hidding the actual system call number is quite common, and it is done by some wrapper routine that includes the kernel header mentioned above, and uses the `#define`d symbol to represent the call number to make the `__SYSCAL(...)` actual call.  That's normally even necessary, as each system call has normally a different interface.  All the normal system calls you use have included wrappers to them in the stdlib, but the new one will not be included.  You have two approaches here: to patch the standard C library to include (and write a standard header file for the function prototype somewhere in `/usr/include`) **OR** to include the wrapper file `mySysCall.o` (this name is at your convenience) in all the programs in where you are going to use the new syscall.